# Navigation in a simple Eclipse RAP web-application

Tags: web-applications, navigation, osgi, eclipse-rap, eclipse-virgo

I have a feeling that I'm about to ask something obvous/basic here, but I'm a novice when it comes the technologies and have not figured out the "correct" way of doing things so here it goes.

**Background**

I am currently developing a web-application as sort of a hobby project. I have decided to use Eclipse RAP ([RWT Standalone](https://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=rwt-standalone.html&version=3.0)) for the UI. The application will be deployed on [Eclipse Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/) server (Tomcat variant) as I'm planing to take advantage of the OSGI framework *(makes some of the business logic easier to implement, but this is out of the scope of this question)*.

**Problem**

The application will have multiple sections and only one of these should be visible at a time. While setting up RAP was relatively easy, I am having trouble understanding how to set up navigation between the different sections of the application.

What I mean by this is for example having buttons such as "Data" and "Settings" in the application header and the content below these buttons changing depending on which button the user clicks.

**Current solution**

Currently the easiest solution i came up with is to

1. Use the active [Shell](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.help%2Fhelp%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FShell.html) as a parent for the visible section
2. Create a secondary invisible Shell as a parent for all of the inactive sections
3. If the visible section changes then use `currentlyVisibleSection.setParent(backgroundShell)` to move the currently visible section to the background Shell and `newVisibleSection.setParent(activeShell)` to make the selected section visible

This idea is illustrated by the next stripped down example:

```java
public class TestUI extends AbstractEntryPoint {
    private Composite visibleSection;
    private Shell backgroundShell;

    public void createContents( Composite parent ) {
        backgroundShell = new Shell();

        //Implementation comes from other OSGI bundles
        Composite dataSection = createDataSection(parent);
        Composite settingsSection = createSettingsSection(backgroundShell);
        visibleSection = dataSection;

        Button dataButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        dataButton.setText("Data");
        dataButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                if (visibleSection!=dataSection) {
                    visibleSection.setParent(backgroundShell);
                    dataSection.setParent(parent);
                    visibleSection=dataSection;
                    parent.layout();
                }
            }
        });

        Button settingsButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        settingsButton.setText("Data");
        settingsButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                if (visibleSection!=settingsSection) {
                    visibleSection.setParent(backgroundShell);
                    settingsSection.setParent(parent);
                    visibleSection=settingsSection;
                    parent.layout();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously I have stripped away all of the layout and styling code, pluss it would still need some work to look decent for the end user. It does require me to manually keep track of all the different sections, creating them and managing them, but that is acceptable for me. So overall this pretty much does what I need it to do, however it feels a bit "hackish".

**Questions**

- Does this way of doing things have some significant drawbacks or fundamental flaws?
- Is there a better way of doing things by purely using Eclipse RAP?

I also looked a bit into using Eclipse workspaces/perspectives (Workbench), but this seems to add a significant amount of complexity to the application (not to mention the initial learning-curve) and i would prefer to avoid it. Especially because I would not need most of that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StackLayout` is the recommended way to display a stack of control where only one will be visible at a time.

The example below creates button area to show the selection buttons ("Data", "Settings", ...) at the top of the parent and the container takes the remaining space. All sections are created within the container that uses a `StackLayout`.

```java
parent.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );
Composite buttonArea = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE );
buttonArea.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false ) );

Composite container = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE );
container.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ) );
StackLayout containerLayout = new StackLayout();
container.setLayout( containerLayout );
Composite dataSection = createDataSection( container );
Composite settingsSection = createDataSection( container );
```

The selection listener code tells the layout which section is to be shown.

```java
dataButton.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent event ) {
    containerLayout.topControl = dataSection;
    container.layout();
  }
});
```

Fore more on layouts see also this article: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

You are on the right track. Don't use the workbench ("workspaces/perspectives" as you called it), it adds much more than you will probably need. Besides, certain parts of that stack can be used independantly when needed. Like JFace viewers or core commands for example.

Comment: Oddly the StackLayout is not mentioned in the article you referenced (and the article is marked as deprecated). Also none of the tutorials i have seen have mentioned this layout. Nevertheless it seems to be what i was looking for and I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Tested and it works as i hoped. The StackLayout approach seems to be faster and feels more responsive. As a side-note, calling `parent.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );` is redundant as the same layout is given to the `parent` by the framework anyways. The framework does this in `AbstractEntryPoint#createUI()`. However it might be a good idea to set it explicitly in case this part of the framework changes in the future.

Comment: You are right, but the `GridLayout` was set on purpose as the current situation is an implementation detail and the framework does not make any statements about which layout the `parent` has or has not.